# How do I modify CreateThread function?

Tags: c++

Like my title says, I'm trying to modify the CreateThread function. I want it to report the sequence number of the thread using the loop.

I'm fairly new to programming in C++ and am unsure which parameter needs to be altered. I suspect it may be the 'lpParameter' but after looking on microsofts website (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I still do not understand how the parameters work.

So far I have:

```
int int_tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
HANDLE hThread[numThreads];
int tNum[10];
for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
{
    tNum[i] = i;
    hThread[i] =
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, helloFun, NULL, 0, NULL);
}   WaitForMultipleObjects(numThreads, hThread, TRUE, INFINITE);

return 0;
}
```

Which produces a blank thread.

EDIT:

Sorry for the confusion guys. I have declared the thread routine:

```
const int numThreads = 4; 
DWORD WINAPI helloFun(LPVOID pArg)
{

    printf("Hello Thread \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Eh? You can't modify the `CreateThread()` function. It's in the operating system.

Comment: @EJP: I think he wants to modify his thread procedure.  Calling a thread procedure a "CreateThread function" does not require much suspension of disbelief (much as the function passed to `qsort` could be reasonably described as a sort function, even though it is really a comparison function)

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are trying to do, but it is clear that you are calling `WaitForMultipleObjects` in the wrong place.

You are trying to wait for `numThreads` after only creating one thread.  The rest of the `hThread` array is still uninitialized, and passing wild handles to `WaitForMultipleObjects` is a terrible idea.

Move the wait call outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your thread routine must be declared

```
DWORD name (LPVOID whatever)
```

Whatever is passed as lpParameter is passed to the thread. In this case, cast integer to pointer and back.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, if you want to pass a parameter to the thread, then you use the lpParameter. It expects a pointer, so you could pass, for instance, `&i`, although that's not exactly a good idea. You could create a pointer to int, and pass it, and then delete after `WaitForMultipleObjects`returns.

As Ben said, you are calling `WaitForMultipleObjects` in the wrong place.

Something like this should work:

```
int int_tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
HANDLE hThread[numThreads];
int tNum[10];
int *parameters[numThreads];
for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
{
    tNum[i] = i;
    parameters[i] = new int(i);
    hThread[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, helloFun, (void *)parameters[i], 0, NULL);
}
WaitForMultipleObjects(numThreads, hThread, TRUE, INFINITE);

for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
    delete parameters[i];

return 0;
}
```

You will have to cast the lpParameter to int in your `helloFun`.

Comment: You don't need to dynamically allocate the integers in this example.  As long as the integer array outlives the threads (which it will, because of `WaitForMultipleObjects()`), you can use `int parameters[numThreads]` and then pass `&parameters[i]` to `CreateThread()`.

Comment: Unnecessary cast to `void*`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this:

```
const int maxThreads = 4; 

DWORD WINAPI helloFun(LPVOID pArg)
{
    int num = * (int*) pArg;
    printf("Hello from Thread %d\n", num);
    return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HANDLE hThread[maxThreads];
    int tNum[maxThreads];
    int numThreads = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < maxThreads; i++)
    {
        tNum[numThreads] = i+1;
        hThread[numThreads] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &helloFun, &tNum[numThreads], 0, NULL);
        if (hThread[numThreads] == NULL)
        { 
            printf("Unable to create a thread! Error: %u\n", GetLastError());
            break;
        }
        ++numThreads;
    }

    if (numThreads > 0)
    {
        WaitForMultipleObjects(numThreads, hThread, TRUE, INFINITE);

        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
            CloseHandle(hThread[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First line of `helloFun` has a compile error, due to mismatched indirection.